# Should I keep a wrecked Canon EOS Rebel t6s (760D) as repair pieces for a 80D?

Tags: canon, repair, repair-parts

I've got a Canon EOS Rebel T6s (760D) which stopped working after its electronic start system was destroyed by a fall. It also has some dead pixels, so I decided not to fix it. I was thinking about selling it to a technician so he can use its good pieces for cheap replacement, but I also have a Canon 80D, and I've read somewhere (don't remember where) that these models share some parts.

Would it be justified to keep the T6s in case I need replacement for any 80D part?

Comment: The T6s and 80D are very different cameras on the outside. I wouldn't expect them to share any internal parts either. I would just sell it for parts.

Comment: If you have to ask instead of already knowing the answer, probably not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They *could* share the same sensor (24.2mp), mount ring, screws, stuff like that.  The LCD specs are the same, so *could* be compatible.  The mirror assembly and shutter are probably different because the specs are different.

Even if there are significant usable parts, are you *capable* of swapping them yourself?  Suppose you swapped the sensor, are you able to realign it for correct focus?  If not, you're better off getting what you can from anyone who's willing to buy it. This would be the case even if you had two copies of the same model.